# ST_Snap doing weird things

Tags: postgis, snapping

Consider the following query:

```
WITH geoms AS(
    SELECT 
    ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(10,10),5,200) as circle,
    ST_MakeEnvelope(5,5,15,15) as square
)
SELECT ST_Snap(square,circle,15) geom FROM geoms;
```

I would expect two possible outcomes:

1. The square being made completely into a circle (points are being introduced to the segments)
2. The 4 vertices of the square are snapped to their closest neighbours on the circle (the square would fit into the circle)

but the actual outcome is this:

[image: square to circle]

The other way around makes more sense (ST_Snap(circle, square,15)):
[image: circle to square]

Here, only 4 vertices are snapped to their corresponding nearest square neigbours.

I don't understand what happens in the first case. Somebody else does?
(my real use-case is more complex, but seems to boil down to this problem)